# How to sort MultipleSelectorRow values in Eureka library in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, set, eureka-forms

My use case describes the necessity of a field in which the user can select multiple phases that goes from A to F. To achieve that I used the MultipleSelectorRow n Eureka library:

```
<<< MultipleSelectorRow<String>("phase") {
        $0.title = "Phase"
        $0.options = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
    }
```

When the user selects any of the options I want the value to display the selected options in alphabetical order "A,B,C...", what happens is that the text is always displayed in a random order, I've tried to achieve the alphabetical order by extending the code:

```
<<< MultipleSelectorRow<String>("phase") {
        $0.title = "Phase"
        $0.options = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
    }.onChange { row in
        row.value = Set(row.value!.sort())
    }
```

The expression is evaluated correctly, but I still can't get the values sorted in the alphabetical order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While posting the question I realize that as Eureka uses a [Set](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) to store the fields it will never be sorted.

In this case I've changed the cellUpdate method to update the detailTextLabel with the sorted values as stated bellow:

```
<<< MultipleSelectorRow<String>("phase") {
        $0.title = "Phase"
        $0.options = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
    }.cellUpdate { cell, row in
        if (row.value != nil) {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text =  row.value!.sort().joinWithSeparator(", ")
        }
    }
```

I also proposed a fix on the Eureka library to sort alphabetically by default. More details on https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/pull/474

**Update**
This was fixed and released on Eureka 1.7.0 (2016.07.07)